# Samba 4 - The server is not operational error message

Tags: windows, samba, active-directory

I just went through the Samba 4 setup guide, with no prior domain. I'm using the Internal DNS Server offered by the Samba 4 package. I can connect to see shared folders, and access most features in the Windows RSAT, as described.

However, a lot of features are missing that should be there. I am also getting a very annoying message a lot of the time, simply stating `The server is not operational`. This is happening when I use ANY of the Active Directory admin tools from my Windows PC.

I tried troubleshooting steps along the way. I know DNS works on the server. I know kerberos works. I can connect with `smbclient` on my Linux Server.

What is happening? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fix had to do with DNS. An [article about Microsoft Exchange having the same error message](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/325322) by Microsoft tipped me off.

The computer I was using to administer the Active Directory was one that I move between many sites. It was not set to use the new Samba server as a DNS server. After I went into my Adapter's Properties, I could **set the DNS server to JUST be the Linux box**. Once I OK'd out, all the Active Directory Remote Administration Tools connected perfectly fine!

(This also fixes issues with permissions, and annoying issues with Active Directory Users and Computers when viewing certain Properties pages - IE on the User Accounts tab, "the pre windows 2000 logon name cannot be displayed" and "You cannot modify domain or trust information because a PDC emulator cannot be contacted", along with other fun messages that don't describe the issue.)